# Generator with parameters?

Tags: python, parameters, generator

Is there a way to create a parametrized Generator.

I want a generator/counter that increases if I pass True and decreases if I pass False.

```
 next(gen(True))
 1
 next(gen(True))
 2
 next(gen(False))
 1
```

---

if it falls back below zero I want to end the iteration.

I'm using this generator to implement Backtracking i.e. falling below zero is the case when all options are exhausted.

reaching the to upper bound is dynamic. In case I can not integrate it i can do the check outside.

Having generator allows me to do the cycle logic as simple while-loop.

As mentioned may be I may also explore Callable object.

Comment: Looks like you're creating three generators (generator iterators) there. Is that what you mean? What exactly is `gen` meant to be?

Comment: you can `.send` to generators

Comment: Why shall it be a generator? Might as well just make `gen` a callable object returning the numbers when called, and then drop all the `next` calls.

Comment: probably .. could be !!hmm

Answer (score 4):

There is no native syntax for this (yet?), but this behavior can be mimicked:

```
class IntakeGen(object): 
    counter = None 
   
    def __init__(self, counter=0): 
        self.counter = counter 

    def __call__(self, increase): 
        self.counter += 1 if increase else -1 
        return self 

    def __next__(self):
        return self.counter
```

Use:

```
In [7]: gen = IntakeGen()                                                                                   

In [8]: next(gen(True))                                                                                
Out[8]: 1

In [9]: next(gen(True))                                                                                
Out[9]: 2

In [10]: next(gen(False))                                                                              
Out[10]: 1
```

Comment: you can use the `send` method instead `next` to use the behaviour

Comment: `send` only works with `generator` values, not iterators in general.

Comment: If you define a `generator`, yes. But `IntakeGen` is a different type.

Answer (score 4):

If `gen` is a value of type `generator`, you can use its `send` method. `next(gen)` is essentially the same as `gen.send(None)` (one of which must be used to start a new generator).

```
def make_gen():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        if (yield counter):
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter -= 1
```

Then

```
>>> gen = make_gen()
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> gen.send(True)
1
>>> gen.send(True)
2
>>> gen.send(False)
1
```

Comment: how do i end it ... w/o raising err.. this doesnt seem to work ....   if counter == 0 : return StopIteration()

Comment: You need to *raise* `StopIteration`, not return it. You can use `return` (short for `return None`), which is effectively the same as `raise StopIteration` in a generator function.

Comment: Note, though, that the `send` method is intended for using `generator`s as coroutines, not iterables.

Comment: fails instead of simply ending  ..   [ g.send(i) for i in [True, True, False, False, False]]

Comment: Works for me. Keep in mind that you have to call `g.send(None)` (or `next(gen)`) at least once before you start passing other values to `send`, and there is no need to raise `StopIteration`. You aren't iterating over `g` here; you are iterating over the list of Booleans and simply calling `g`'s `send` method on each Boolean value.

Comment: Your question is lacking any context for why you want special behavior when/if the counter hits zero, or what that behavior should be.

Comment: implementing Backtracking

Comment: That doesn't clear up why you want `g` to be a generator when you aren't iterating over it directly.

Comment: thats why i'm also considering caller obj

Answer (score 3):

```
def gen(v, start_val=[0]):
    start_val[0] += 1 if v else -1
    yield start_val[0]

print( next(gen(True)) )
print( next(gen(True)) )
print( next(gen(False)) )
```

Prints:

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: Wow, pretty cool use of mutable defaults. I don't know about readability, but it is damn smart

Comment: why was it not just `start_val=0`?

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan Because `0` is immutable, but `[0]` is list and that's muttable object.

Comment: Ohh, you are yeilding, got it. Nice one

Comment: Meh, at this point I really don't see the point of making it a generator at all. Could just make it an ordinary function returning one number and drop the `next` calls: https://repl.it/repls/DazzlingClearWebsite#main.py